# JTA persist does not work with REST POST service

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, ejb

I have a very weird problem with Jersey REST services. I'm using:

- Glassfish
- sh4.0
- EJB3.1
- JDK1.7
- Netbeans8.0

When I persist an object by GET request it normally store in database:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/person")
public class SampleRest {

    @EJB
    PersonFasade personFasade;

    @GET
    public Person getPerson1(
            final @QueryParam("id") String id,
            final @QueryParam("first") String first,
            final @QueryParam("last") String last) 
    {
        final Person person = this.personFasade.create(id, first, last);        
        return person;
    }

}
```

But when I'm using POST:

```
...

    @POST
    public Person getPerson3(Person person) {
        this.personFasade.create(person);    
        return person;
    }
...
```

Everything works but Object does not store in database (without any error)!!

Comment: Can you include your PersonFacade implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was because I forgot to put beans.xml into WEB-INF folder!!! I don't know how it is possible to such things happen by this mistake!! After I did it works. I switch to Wildfly, seems it's more stable, with very good useful logs and error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is the parameter, you should use the @Consumes annotation to pass a Person object as JSON/XML parameter or use the same @QueryParam annotations to describe the object to persist.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person getPerson3(Person person) {
    this.personFasade.create(person);    
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found the problem! It was because I forgot to put beans.xml into WEB-INF folder!!! I don't know how it is possible to such things happen by this mistake!! After I did it works. I switch to JBoss, seems it's more stable with very good useful logs and error message.